# Laravel shows Text content false

Tags: php, laravel

Hello does anyone has a solve for this problem.

I have a textarea input.

if I tip in like:

```
test
test
```

Its comes to the db as

```
test
test
```

but if i make the output at the view with `{!! parseDown($post->description) !!}`

its show this:

```
test test
```

if I make a input with

```
test

test
```

its shows :

```
test

test
```

does anyone knows what I can make that the output is the same?

function behind parseDown

```
function parseDown($text = null)
{
    return Parsedown::instance()
        ->setMarkupEscaped(true)# escapes markup (HTML)
        ->text($text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function when displaying the content of textarea.

Comment: thats won't work that change the text to html and the parsedown escape html markup n2br only work If I turn it of.

Comment: Instead of using you function parseDown how about `nl2br(htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8", false));`?